# reading password from user using ansible

Tags: ansible

I have some code to read password from a user and write it in a file, I entered the password **cPUtnZjn$s2O** but got **cPUtnZjn** in the output file.

```
---
- name: read password
  hosts: all
  vars_prompt:
    - name: admin_password
      prompt: "enter password for admin"
      private: no
  tasks:
    - name: modify database
      shell: |
       echo 'database_driver: pdo_mysql
       database_host: 127.0.0.1
       database_password: '{{admin_password}}'' > /root/admin_password
```

output

```
database_driver: pdo_mysql
database_host: 127.0.0.1
database_password: cPUtnZjn
```

how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you quote your string is wrong as you are getting out of the single quote to output the password. `$s2O` is then interpreted by your shell as an environment variable. Since id does not exists, it is empty. The following should get the result you expect:

```
- name: modify database
  shell: |
    echo 'database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_password: {{ admin_password }}' > /root/admin_password
```

If you really need to have single quotes surrounding the password in your result you can do the following (warning: quoting hell ahead...):

```
- name: modify database
  shell: |
    echo "database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_password: '"'{{ admin_password }}'"'" > /root/admin_password
```